# Screen sharing snap applications

Tags: permissions, firefox, snap

Recently, I have been using Ubuntu as a platform to tutor a Data Structures & Algorithms course remotely. I decided the best way to go about teaching remotely would be to use my drawing tablet and an excellent doodling application. So, I opened up my snap store and install an application called "OpenBoard" from the Flathub repository. Upon getting everything set up and logging into WebEx via Firefox -- also installed via the snap store -- I attempted to share my OpenBoard window using Firefox's screen share mechanism. Much to my chagrin, Firefox would not list the application as a shareable application. Another attempt was using Discord -- also installed via the snap store -- to screen share with a similar result, the application not appearing as a streamable application. Eventually, I settled on using an online whiteboard and sharing a window of Firefox instead, which works fine. But this hasn't stopped me from attempting to get to the bottom of this.

I was wondering if anyone has had a similar issue with snap applications, in particular, OpenBoard. Also if anyone would have any additional information on how to configure applications so I could screen share any application I wanted.

*Note. A working version of OpenBoard cannot be installed via the Snap store and must be installed via the Flatpak store.*

Comment: Do you manage to run openboard installed through snap? For me, no icon appears and `snap run openboard` yields `error: cannot find app "openboard" in "openboard"`. `snap list openboard` yields `openboard  0.1      14   latest/stable  arturu     -`, so the snap is installed. Or is it installed via flathub? (Your question is not clear on that point). If so, I also cannot share the application, although sharing your entire screen will always work.

Comment: I found that installing this through flathub works best (version 1.5.4). The default Ubuntu repository appears to provide a broken verison of OpenBoard.

Comment: So please clarify your post on that: you cannot install flatpaks from the Snap store. You may instead have installed gnome-software and the flatpak plugin. I have been looking into this. Did not find anything lacking in the permissions. It could be that it is not related to the fact that it is a flatpak. Gimp from flatpak can be shared.